# Calling Model from Collection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

Collection

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone){
    console.log("Loaded");

    var Jobs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: function () {
            return 'http://domain.com/api/jobs?page='+this.page+''
        },
        page: 1
    });
    return Jobs;
});
```

Model

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone){
    var JobFilterModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            T: '1',  
            PT: '1',  
            C: '1',  
            I: '1'  
        }
    });
    // Return the model for the module
    return JobFilterModel;
});
```

In one of my view , i SET the models

```
 var jobListFilterModelUpdate = new JobListFilterModel();
            jobListFilterModelUpdate.set({value:isChecked});
```

I'm trying to retrieve the MODEL from Collection so i can send the correct QUERY with the URL.

**Question 1**

How do i retrieve from Model from Collection

**Question 2**

Will the retrieved collection be the updated Model with the data i Set in View?

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a `Collection` you need to specify a `model` property, something like :

```
var Jobs = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: function () {
            return 'http://punchgag.com/api/jobs?page='+this.page+''
        },
        page: 1,
        model: JobFilterModel
    });
```

After creating a new model you need to add it to collection (assuming you have `jobsCollection` created):

```
var jobListFilterModelUpdate = new JobListFilterModel();
jobListFilterModelUpdate.set({value:isChecked}); 
jobsCollection.add(jobListFilterModelUpdate);
```

**Answer 1**

You can retrieve a model from a collection based on `id`, `collection.get(id)`. Here `JobFilterModel` doesn't seem to have any id (you can set `idAttribute` property of `Model` to create custom `id` property). Backbone also creates unique ids at client side but I don't know how would they be of any help to you. If you want to retrieve a model based on any of model's property you can use [collection.findWhere()](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere) or [collection.where()](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where).

**Answer 2**

Yes. It will be but it depends on how link your `View` to `Collection`.

Comment: My Collection has URL , i want to retrieve the data from model before i run the URL. Hmm How do i get All the data inside default(model) and read it from collection?